# Can't create indexes on really large table!

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with over 300 Million rows in it.  When I try to create an index on the table I get the error message below.

> Msg 1105, Level 17, State 2, Line 3 Could not allocate space for
>   object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  422212472471552' in database
>   'MSD' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by
>   deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding
>   additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for
>   existing files in the filegroup.

When I look at the files, the one using the PRIMARY file group is set to grow by 10% and is unrestricted for max size.  My hard drive still has 500 gigs of space left on it.  Does anyone know why I am hitting this problem and how I can get around it?

Comment: I see.  @MartinSmith, if you want to put that as an answer I will accept?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to temporarily set the recovery model to `Simple`.

Alternatively, you can tell the `create index` command to use `tempdb`.  Since `tempdb` is typically in the `Simple` recovery mode.

```
CREATE INDEX ...
WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

uu run out of database space. This can happen if:
1) If autogrow is off. In this case, you need to extend the database manually.(tempdb)
2) Autogrow is on, but there is not room on the disk.

if autogrow is 10% and this translates to 30GB, this means if you only have 20GB free, you get an error.

Are you specifying the SORT_IN_TEMPDB option on the CREATE INDEX?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Express Edition, you may be hitting the 4/10GB per database limit.- [martin-smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith)

The limit was originally 4GB, then raised to 10GB in the 2008 R2 release. - [jon-seigel](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2718/jon-seigel)